# Filtering for blocks (with headers) containing content in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have an output that looks like this:

```
foo-2
===========
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
foo-54
===========
foo-26
===========
```

How do I print only what has text under it? Meaning, for this example its foo-3. But I also want it to work if the data appears in foo-54 as well...

```
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
```

I've trying "playing" with sed: `sed -n '/foo/,/^foo/!p'`, but it doesn't print the foo-3 itself + unnecessary ===== prints.

Thanks!

EDIT:

1. Re-reading the answers, I've apparently asked the wrong question. I don't know where my data is (whether its in foo-3 or foo-XXXXX).
2. It doesn't have to be with sed. sed and awk are my "comfort zone"... Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if we have a line that starts with `foo` but doesn't have a line of `=====` after it? Does that count as a header, or does it not? (If we want to treat such lines as content, the solution gets significantly more complicated).

Comment: `I don't know where my data is (whether its in foo-3 or foo-XXXXX)` How do you know where to start then?  You only want block with date within it?

Comment: Yes. only the blocks that contain data. Those that do not, I don't want. (I seem to have a problem to describe my question)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I would prefer the latter, but the basic would suffice for now...

Comment: The new question is so different from the old one that it'd probably be better asked separately.

Comment: Try my updated version.  It should print data section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edit I think this gnu-awk solution should be simplest/smallest script:

```
awk -v ORS= -v RS='foo-[0-9]+\n=+\n' '!NF{p=RT} NF{print p $0}' file
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
```

**Earlier Solution:**

```
sed -n '/^foo-3/,/^foo/{/foo-3/p; /foo-/!p;}' f
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! Helpful. But re-reading my own original question, made me think I mislead you :( sorry

Comment: So how do we know which block you want to print from input?

Comment: the one that has "data" in it. all the others are have nothing under the '====='

Comment: @Maxim_united: ok I got it, check my edited answer now.

Comment: Works well with the original input I gave! However it doesn't if there's more than one block to match...

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n '/^foo-3/, ${/^foo-[^3]/q; p}' input
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
```

---

A better solution using awk would be

```
$ awk 'flag && /^foo/{flag=0} /^foo-3$/{flag++} flag' input 
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
```

Comment: I was searching the way to go in awk, you gimme the solution with `flag && /^foo/{flag=0}` +1 =)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk '!(/^foo/ || $0~sep) {data=data RS $0;next} data {print header RS sep data RS;data=""} /^foo/ {header=$0}' sep="===========" file
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
```

---

Some more readable:

```
awk '
!(/^foo/ || $0~sep) {
    data=data RS $0
    next}
data {
    print header "\n"sep data
    data=""}
/^foo/ {
    header=$0}
' sep="===========" file
```

---

cat file

```
foo-2
===========
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah
foo-34
===========
more data
test this
foo-26
===========
```

gives

```
foo-3
===========
bar bar bar
yadda yadda
blah blah

foo-34
===========
more data
test this
```

Comment: How did it print `foo-34` ? It should be in foo-3

Comment: One of only two answers here that reflects the clarified question.

Answer (score 0):

In pure native bash, printing only blocks with content (and their headers):

```
#!/bin/bash

sep="==========="
last_line=''
header=''
content=( )
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = $sep ]]; then
    if (( ${#content[@]} )); then
      printf '%s\n' "$header" "$sep" "${content[@]}"
    fi
    header=$last_line
    content=( )
  else
    [[ $last_line && $last_line != $sep ]] && content+=( "$last_line" )
  fi
  last_line=$line
done
```